# Read xls file in android

Tags: android, android-emulator

I know their is same Q. for it
I try to use both apache poi and jexcel but when I import poi/jexcel in project still my code shows undefined word workbook and also org.apache.poi..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just Attach `jxl.jar` and `poi-3.0.2-FINAL.jar` files in `prokect.its`.

Comment: I want to read xls contents and stored it into sqlite-db

Comment: ok..I done this thing..First download jxl.jar & poi-3.0.2-final.jar file and attach it..can u possible to post ur code here??

Comment: what do u want?? import contact in phone ya export contact from phone and create backup file in sd card as xls??

Comment: xls has some data like Name, addr, number time etc..
till am referring this github.com/dennis-sheil/android-spreadsheet/blob/master/src/com/vartmp/android/spreadsheet/Spreadsheet.java

Comment: http://onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2003/04/16/poi_excel.html    Read carefully...if u want more plz ask